# Casting a custom collection type in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom method that returns a collection:

```
 Course[] catalog = clnt.GetCatalog(new Guid(CurrentUser.MembershipGUID));
```

I then pass it to my ViewData object:

```
 ViewData["catalog"] = catalog;
```

But when i try to access it on my aspx page like so:

```
   var catalog = ViewData["catalog"] as Course[];
```

Here's the method being called:

```
    public List<Course> GetCatalog()
    {

        using (var db = new BALmsDBContainer())
        {
            List<Course> lst = db.Courses.Include(i => i.Vendor).ToList();
          return lst;
        }
     }
```

I get catalog is null. My ViewData["catalog"] object is not null. 100%  guarantee on that. How do i cast the ViewData["catalog"] object back to Course[]?

Comment: What type is being returned from `clnt.GetCatalog()`? Also, what happens if you try `var catalog = (Course[])ViewData["catalog"];`?

Comment: Course[] is being returned. Its a custom class

Comment: You may be having a serialization problem. Is your Course object marked Serializable or as a DataContract?

Comment: are you sure catalog  is not null?

Comment: I'm positive. Im checking if ViewData["catalog"] != null first

Comment: When i tried (Course[]ViewData["catalog"] i get the following:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'Lms.Course[]'

Comment: That error means that the data type is `DataTable`, and not `Course[]`.  How is that even able to compile as well because your `GetCatalog()` method returns a `List<Course>` and not `Course[]` ?

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't even compile, because `GetCatalog()` does not return `Course[]`. Also, your code never mentions `DataTable`, which seems is what `ViewData["catalog"]`. Could you post code that actually reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var catalog = (Course)ViewData["catalog"]
```

The "as" operator is actually different from an explicit cast, as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: public List<Course> GetAllCourses()
        {
            _traceSource.TraceInformation("GetAllCourses");
            using (var db = new BALmsDBContainer())
            {
                List<Course> lst = db.Courses.Include(i => i.Vendor).ToList(); return lst;}}

Comment: It's only different in **how** it will report failure, not **if** it is going to fail. Provided `ViewData["catalog"] != null`, if `as` returns `null`, then a cast will simply throw an exception, but it still won't work. If `ViewData["catalog"] == null`, both `as` and cast will return `null`.

Comment: I'm checking for ViewData["catalog"] != null before i do anything

Comment: When i try (Course[])ViewData["catalog"] i get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'Lms.Course[]"

Comment: Are you sure ViewData["catalog"] isn't being set somewhere else? Otherwise I can't imagine where that DataTable is coming from...

Comment: Good answer. ViewData["catalog"] was being set somewhere else (yes i inherited this project) I changed it to ViewData["catalogsss"] and its working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @user1202717 I don't think I would mark this answer as correct. The solution had nothing to do with the differences between `as` and explicit casts. Further, the cast above would fail anyway since it should be `(Course[])`, not `(Course)`.